# Android MVP - when retaining presenter in headless fragment how to ensure view gets update during config change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp

Theres lots of stuff online about wrapping a presenter into a headless fragment and setting onretaininstance to true. which keeps the fragment from being destroyed.  But lets say the presenter was in the middle of a network download and a configuration change occured. The activity is about to be recreated but in the middle of the onCreate call the presenter gets the info and has NO VIEW to deliver to as onCreate did not finish (or did not start yet).  so the presenter has this data it would like to update the view with but there is no view yet. Its a timing issue.

How to resolve timing issues like this?

Comment: Google I/O 2010 - Android REST applications https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about maintaining data in presenter. Make sure you retain the instance of presenter and update fragment reference to presenter.

If you already have data in presenter just update it on resume of fragment else presenter will give a call back.

Answer (score 1):

### TL; DR

[*Always start long term operations from a service*.](https://youtu.be/xHXn3Kg2IQE?t=48m5s) (or a [`JobScheduler`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFN3MrnNhZA))

### Description

If you are downloading a reasonably big file, use the presenter to trigger an [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) (or [`JobScheduler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) for Android Marshmallow and later), never [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [`Thread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or any asynchronous structure that would callback to the main thread.

The presenter survives to `onPause`, but not to `onDestroy`, so if the application be killed by the operating system the reference to the activity/fragment will be lost anyway.

If you are running the download in a service, your presenter can check if the file already exists and updates the activity/fragment properly.

Remember that the fragment being destroyed is actually good for the OS, so use early/often persistence of network data :-)

Comment: in my case it will not be a file per say but just json info for my model. i mean there can be a timing issue at anytime.  Actually now i am thinking the accepted answer is not good enough. because the request could have been completed before the activity is even created or before the view is attached to the presenter. can you help ? i still see a timing issue.

Comment: You can create a repository that keeps both local and remote data synced. Take a look at Android Architecture Blueprints https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture

Comment: @CommonsWare looking at your article https://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/10/asynctask-screen-rotation.html it would seem i dont have to worry about android passing messages during a config change until onCreate is called. no messages will be passed during a config change. this will avoid the timing issue i am talking about. right ?